# Perl Sort a hash by value in descending order and then key in ascending order

Tags: perl, sorting

Suppose I have a hash like

```
%hash = 
{
    husky => 2
    alaska => 2
    akita => 3
    brand =>1
}
```

How can I sort it by descending value(number), and ascending key(alphabet)? The desired result should be:

```
{
    akita =>3
    alaska =>2
    husky =>2
    brand=>1
}
```

Comment: Hashes are inherently unordered, but see [Hash::Ordered](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Ordered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash in Perl is not ordered nor it can be ordered. This is because the *hash* algorithm will spread the keys at random. A hash is defined like this:

```
my %hash = (
  key1 => value1,
  key2 => value2,
);
```

That is, it is defined with a list of value pairs `key => value`. If you want a collection of ordered items, you need to use a list. It is defined like:

```
my @list = ( 1, 2, 3 );
```

You may define a list of hash refs (closer to what you want) like this:

```
my @list = (
  { key1 => value1 },
  { key2 => value2 },
);
```

A hash ref is a reference to a hash, and it is defined with `{` and `}`.

So solving your problem, we have:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (
  husky => 2,
  alaska => 2,
  akita => 3,
  brand =>1,
);

my @list = map { { $_ => $hash{$_} } } 
           sort { $hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a} or $a cmp $b }
           keys %hash;

print Dumper(@list);
```

`keys %hash` will give you a list of the keys in the hash. `sort` will sort elements in a list. As we want a special ordering, we provide the *body* of the sorting bit using the operators `<=>` to compare numbers and `cmp` to compare strings. Each returns `-1` if the left side is less than the right side; `0` if they are the same and `1` if the left side is more than the right side. The `or` will enter the second comparison if the first is `0`.

Finally, `map` will transform the list of keys (ordered) into a list of hash refs.

`Dumper` is a function that creates a human readable text representation of any Perl data structure.

The final output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'akita' => 3
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'alaska' => 2
        };
$VAR3 = {
          'husky' => 2
        };
$VAR4 = {
          'brand' => 1
        };
```

Comment: Did you mis-speak in your explanation?  I thought 'cmp' is to compare strings while '<=>' is to compare numbers.   Your code seems consistent with my understanding.  Overall excellent, concise and detailed explanations.

Comment: @ShangZhang Yes, it was a typo. I have edited the answer to fix it. Thanks a lot.